# Errors while installing jars to maven in windows 10 command prompt

Tags: maven

- Command prompt:
  [image]
- Errors in cmd
  [image]

I'm not able to install **`ojdbc6.jar`**, **`aqapi.jar`**, **`jmscommon.jar`**, **`xdb.jar`** for maven using command prompt with commands like

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D://software//mjars//ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=oracle-jdbc -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Command prompt shows error like

> ERROR: No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\VA20075083.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

I'm not able to understand the HELP1 they provided. Can somebody help me out

_ Command prompt and paths screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a network connectivity issue. General recommendations here: check your network connection settings and verify that DNS names are properly resolved. After I fixed my DNS settings, mvn started working.